# how can I fetch data from php to my jquery script in a desired json format?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a query `Select name, age from users` and I want it to return the content to jquery with a specific format:

```
var externalDataRetrievedFromServer = [
    { name: 'Bartek', age: 34 },
    { name: 'John', age: 27 },
    { name: 'Elizabeth', age: 30 },
];
```

On a php side so far I have:

```
$fetch = "SELECT name, age from users";
$result = $mysqli->query($fetch);
$data = array();    
$data = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
echo json_encode( $data );
```

and on jquery site I have:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: './getJson.php', 
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                users: users
            },
            dataType:'text',
            success: function(ans)
            {

                alert(ans);
```

but it returns me data in a format:

```
[{"name":"Bartek","age":"34"},{"name":"John","age":"27"},{"name":"Elizabeth","age":"30"}]
```

I need the specific format that I mentioned at the beginning of my post, because now my current logic (that I don't want to change) throws me an error: `data.forEach is not a function` in this line:

```
function buildTableBody(data, columns) {
        var body = [];

        body.push(columns);

        data.forEach(function(row) {
            var dataRow = [];

            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                dataRow.push(row[column].toString());
            })

            body.push(dataRow);
        });

        return body;
    }
```

where data is the data in a format that I have right now. So how can I change the format?

---

A little bit more details here:

I'm using buildTableBody() here:

```
function table(data, columns) {
            return {
                table: {
                    headerRows: 1,
                    body: buildTableBody(data, columns)
                }
            };
        }
```

However, when I changed the datatype from text to json, I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

from the method `buildTableBody`.

When I do `alert(ans)` now, I'm getting:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Do you have any clues how could I fix it?

---- another edit:

This is exactly what I want to achieve:

var externalDataRetrievedFromServer = [
    { name: 'Bartek', age: 34 },
    { name: 'John', age: 27 },
    { name: 'Elizabeth', age: 30 },
];

function buildTableBody(data, columns) {
    var body = [];

```
body.push(columns);

data.forEach(function(row) {
    var dataRow = [];

    columns.forEach(function(column) {
        dataRow.push(row[column].toString());
    })

    body.push(dataRow);
});

return body;
```

}

function table(data, columns) {
    return {
        table: {
            headerRows: 1,
            body: buildTableBody(data, columns)
        }
    };
}

var dd = {
    content: [
        { text: 'Dynamic parts', style: 'header' },
        table(externalDataRetrievedFromServer, ['name', 'age'])
    ]
}

Comment: It's a quick hack but you could use str_replace on $data to swap the : and , around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forEach for the rows, $.each for the columns.

DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/0cc3bgp2/

```
var x = '[{"name":"Bartek","age":"34"},{"name":"John","age":"27"},{"name":"Elizabeth","age":"30"}]';

var rows = $.parseJSON(x);

rows.forEach(function(row) {

    var dataRow = [];

    $.each(row, function(index, value) {
      dataRow.push(value);
    });

    //body.push(dataRow);
    console.log(dataRow);
});

// WILL LOG:
//
// ["Bartek", "34"]
// ["John", "27"]
// ["Elizabeth", "30"]
```

Comment: @charlietfl OP said "because now my current logic (that I don't want to change) throws me an error: data.forEach is not a function in this line". I'm pointing out what can be parsed with forEach and what with $.each. Also, this is before OP's edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting  `dataType:'text'` so the response will be returned to `success` callback as a string.

Since there is no `String.prototype.forEach()` you get an error

Change to `dataType:'json'` and jQuery will parse the response to array internally.

It is not shown where you call `buildTableBody()` to be able to assist any further

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Could you please check my updated question?

Comment: Still unknowns , where does `columns` come from? Not showing where the function `table()` is called

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it before! I'm using an answer to this post https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/24 here, the code written bybpampuch - is that helpful for you in my case?

Comment: Have no interest in reading all that....questions should be self contained with all relevant code